# Trying to understand php function call_user_func found in a book example

Tags: php

The example comes from the book "Professional PHP5" by Edward Lecky-Thompson.

```
  function __get($propertyName) {
  if(!array_key_exists($propertyName, $this->propertyTable))
     throw new Exception("Błędna własność \"$propertyName\"!");

  if(method_exists($this, 'get' . $propertyName)) {
     return call_user_func(array($this, 'get' . $propertyName));
  } else {
     return $this->data[$this->propertyTable[$propertyName]];
  }
}
```

Can somebody please explain what happens exactly step-by-step in the **call_user_func** function?

On php.net I've read that the first parameter is a function to be called and the remaining parameters are passed to that function as its parameters.

On php.net there were simple examples and I had no problem understanding them. However I don't get it why in the above example there is an array, and why $this as the first element of the array?

P.S.
I found a similar question on stackoverflow, and I understand what the code is supposed to do but I don't understand fully why what's written works.

Here's the link to the similar question:
[PropertyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435508/propertyobject-class-help)

Comment: check below link...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105995/help-with-php-call-user-func-and-integrate-function-into-class?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two-part array is PHP's informal formal convention of passing the **method of a specific object** as a *callback/callable*. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php for details.

`array($this, 'getFoo')` simply stands for *the `getFoo` method of the `$this` object*.

Answer (score 0):

This is used in a [class](http://php.net/class). If `$propertyName = 'Foo'` you are effectively calling the function `$this->getFoo`.

`$this` is always the current object so another way of saying it is that you are calling the function `getFoo` on the current object.